# Nutrition and fitness

Tags: running, weightlifting, diet, nutrition

I have been doing 5×5 Stronglifts three days a week with the same number of running days on the rest (from lifting) days. I have, for a long time, consuming the following type of diet and activity, respectively in sequence:

**Morning**

Coconut oil   (half of a tablespoon)

Running or Lifting for an hour

3 eggs, 100 gram cheese, 1 kiwi, 10 pieces of nut/walnut/almonds, vegetable

Omega-3 pills

**Rest of the day**

500 grams of meat (beef/pork/chicken)
200 grams of Yoghurt
200 grams of Vegetables

The changes I see on my body generally is in the way of horizontal growth, i.e. the back/chest/shoulders are growing in width. I generally seem very fit; but not big, and i feel that i am not having the muscle growth fully.

Should i find my diet guilty for that?

Edit: I am 26 years old. 183 cm and 74 kg male. I don't count the calories, but i would suppose it is around 2600.

Comment: How long have you been following this training program and diet?

Comment: Approximately 2 years.

Comment: You probably need to add in how many calories you are actually eating a day, along with age/weight and gender. A 20 year old female will have different caloric needs than a 55 year old man, and calorie needs vary by bodyweight as well.

Comment: I am 26 years old. 183 cm and 74 kg male. I don't count the calories, but i would suppose it is around 2600.

Comment: Are you gaining or losing weight? 2600 sounds a bit low if you are active and want to gain weight. Also, have you calculated that number and are you sure it's a good guess? My best guess would be that you are eating even less than that, but it depends on the kind of meat (not the animal but how much fat there is in there) and so on

Comment: I eat a significant amount of fat. At least 50 grams of meat is fat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your body's muscle growth will be in response to whatever is stimulated. If you are gaining weight and getting stronger then you need to assess some things. Essentially you are doing a lot of movements for your back, shoulders, and chest so they're building muscle.

Keep in mind your muscle growth is dependent on you being in a caloric surplus meaning your body has extra calories. The idea with working out in your case being that the body uses those extra calories to pack on muscle in the places you train. Take a look into some bodybuilding routines like Push/Pull/Legs or adding in movements to your current 5x5 program.

The most important change right now is your training program because it is a strength based program so of course you will get strong and gain some muscle. However, the program is not designed for creating the best body. Next you really need to start tracking your calories and weight if you want to get a better idea of what is going on. The mirror is deceiving and you may be overeating or under eating which could be affecting your goals.

Hope this helps!